# re-attach a detached entity with no SQL query executed

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have many entities with relationships (`@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne`) and for optimization purposes I'm storing loaded entities in `Cache` (using the `Play Framework` cache).

The cache storing and retrieving is done correctly however when I try to save an entity I got the following exception: `detached entity passed to persist: models.Player`

The entity I'm trying to save (`Player`) was not stored in cache but is accessed from the `User` entity that was in cache: `User` and `Player` are two entities and they have a `@OneToOne` relationship for each other. The `User` entity was stored in cache. I retrieved this entity from cache within another session and I changed the underlying `Player` entity and tried to save it, which gave my the exception.

I looked at the documentation and I did some googling and I found out that I have to re-attach my entity (`Player`) before calling the `save` method.

With `JPA` I saw the `refresh` method but I don't like it because it is reloading the entity from database and **I don't want the entity to be reloaded** because I know my entity **has not been modified** and if I'm using cache it's exactly to avoid database queries.

With `Hibernate` I saw the `update` method which appears to do what I want as even if the entity is already persistent I can call the `contains` method to check it before calling the `update` method.
However I'm wondering if the `update` method accesses the database or only marks the entity to be attached to the session?

What I'm looking for is a solution to automatically re-attach my entities before saving them but without reloading them: I just want them to be in persistent state. Is the `update` method the method I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hibernate.update` method doesn't access database to retrieve any entity information if this is you concern. It adds the entity to the persistent context (re-attach), then HH will execute update-queries to save modification of this tracked entity when you perform flush or the underlying transaction is committed.

But to use it, the entity must had been retrieved in a previous session. You can not pass new object/entity instance to it.